# how to get rid of "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" in c?

Tags: c

I am getting lvalue not modifiable in this expression

```
tmp_ux =tmp_ux+ tau*(-G*tmp_phi*grad_phi_x)/tmp_rho;
```

the variables I am using are

```
double tmp_ux
#define tau 1.0
#define G -6.0
double tmp_phi
double grad_phi_x
double tmp_rho
```

Comment: @CongXu: I don't think that can happen. The output of the preprocessor is a sequence of tokens, so if represented as a text stream, the preprocessor would have to insert whitespace between the two `-` characters rather than putting them side-by-side where they get pasted together as one token. Failure to do this would be a sign of a non-conforming preprocessor, which would not be so surprising, coming from Microsoft...

Comment: If I copy paste that code into visual studio 2008, it works fine

Comment: Also works in my VS2010 and 2012.

Comment: Interesting - MSVC handles the macro replacement fine (ie., the `-` before the `G` macro is treated as a separate token) when it's preprocessing and compiling in the same build operation, but if you look at the preprocessed output there is no whitepaper between the two dashes. So if you compile the preprocessor output separately, it generates a C2105 error. The C2105 error message is slightly different than the OP's (it says `'--' needs l-value`), so I'm not sure if the OP is doing something like this to get his error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the macro `#define G -6.0`, the expression,

```
tmp_ux =tmp_ux+ tau*(  -G  *tmp_phi*grad_phi_x)/tmp_rho;
```

becomes,

```
tmp_ux =tmp_ux+ tau*( --6.0  *tmp_phi*grad_phi_x)/tmp_rho;
```

Here, `--6.0` is illegal as you are trying to decrement `6.0`.

To avoid this, either change the expression as,

```
tmp_ux =tmp_ux+ tau*( (-1) * G*tmp_phi*grad_phi_x)/tmp_rho;
```

---

Or,

As mentioned in comment, it is **very elegant** to define macro as,

```
#define G (-6.0)
```

so, your expression expands as,

```
tmp_ux =tmp_ux+ tau*(  -(-6.0) *tmp_phi*grad_phi_x)/tmp_rho;
```

Both would solve this error.

Comment: or better #define G (-6.0)

Comment: in fact general advice, make your #defines robust, rather than coding around them in the actual code.  Makes for weird flakey code otherwise

Comment: `tmp_ux =tmp_ux+ tau*( --6.0  *tmp_phi*grad_phi_x)/tmp_rho;` is not a possible output for a conforming C preprocessor. It must output `tmp_ux =tmp_ux+ tau*( - -6.0  *tmp_phi*grad_phi_x)/tmp_rho;` or equivalent (note the extra whitespace), in which case this lvalue error should not arise. This is a bug in OP's compiler, which is widely known to be a piece of junk...